# Illegal instruction when running programs from bash

Tags: c++, macos, bash, runtime-error

I have a suite of C++ based programs that I created and compile on Mac 10.8.3.  They work just fine on 10.8.* Macs, but when I try to run them on 10.6.* I get the following message, "Illegal instruction" and that's all that happens.  If I compile these programs on 10.6.* they will work on other 10.6.* Macs.

I have no idea what causes this error message, but I have duplicated it on multiple 10.6.* machines.  There doesn't seem to be a lot of information about the source of this error message.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Broken backward compatibility in the runtime libraries?

Comment: run it in a debugger and see where it fails? Good luck.

Comment: @user1595510: Did you have a chance to check the answer? Did it help?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the "OS X Deployment Target" to 10.6 (in the project Info tab) to create binaries that run on OS X 10.6.